# Autowired ServletContext в Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Имеется класс синглтон. Из нем мне нужно получить путь к корню приложения.

Класс:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "singleton")
public class WebApp {

    private ServletContext servletContext;

    private static Logger LOGGER;

    private static WebApp ourInstance = new WebApp();

    public static WebApp getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private WebApp() {

        System.out.println(servletContext);

    }

    public ServletContext getServletContext() {
        return servletContext;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        this.servletContext = servletContext;
    }
}
```

Но выводиться два раза `null`. То бишь он не инжектится.
Два раза в принципе понятно ибо первый раз инициализирует спринг а второй срабатывает создание объекта в поле класса. (если не так подскажите)

Почему `null`? может я что-то не то делаю.

Comment: `servletContext` не статичное приватное поле, и как бы не старались, оно всегда будет `null` при вызове конструктора

Comment: @MrFylypenko значит вы ничего не слышали про `Dependency Injection`

Answer (score 1):

Spring bean'ы по умолчанию синглтоны, писать специально `@Scope(value = "singleton")`, а тем более заморачиваться с `getInstance` не нужно.

Comment: как мне тогда получить экземпляр `WebApp`, допустим в контроллере?

Comment: @Tsyklop не работает как раз из-за getInstance. Связывание работает только в бинах, а бины должны создаваться контейнером.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev так а как мне его получить в контроллере?

Comment: Объявить у контроллера аннотированное поле соответствующего типа `@Autowired private WebApp webApp`

Answer (score 0):

Если тебе необходимо постучаться к `ServletContext`, то не надо делать каких-то дополнительных утилит. Можно использовать уже имеющиеся средства:

```
@Component
public class BeanUsingServletContext{
    @Autowired 
    private   org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext springContext;

    public void useServletContext(){
        ServletContext servetContext = springContext.getServletContext();
        //далее можно использовать
    }
}
```

Comment: Мне нужен глобальный объект, то бишь сингтон и что бы я смог его получить